# system variable for directory shortcut?

Tags: shortcuts, environment-variables

Is there a way to create a variable `CUSTOM_DIR`, linked to the directory `/home/user/folder1`,

It is that not only in the shell, but for every program, process etc. The `CUSTOM_DIR` refers to that directory ?

It would be great if it's set only at an user login, and anyway in a file in the `/home/user` directory.

I suppose that `.bashrc` file afflicts only shell, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You are so close! Depending on how you want to do it.

Approach 1

If you want it to be in command line, then it's done via .bash_aliases and our Ubuntu .bashrc is already configured for that.  You will find .bash_aliases in your home directory ( ~/ or $HOME )

In your .bash_aliases file, enter each line for each alias you want to set up.  I.e.

```
    alias myweb="cd /var/www"
    alias privfold="cd $HOME/secretfolder"
```

That's for command line if you want to jump straight to a folder.

Approach 2

As for filesystem as itself.  Enter this:

```
  cd /home/myhome
  ln -s /var/www mywww
```

This will create a folder in your home directory at which this folder points to your /var/www (typical location for webserver).   'ln' is a symlink that ties between these two folders.